# Question about follow up from faculty interview

Tags: faculty-application, interview

I recently interviewed at a R1 institution in the US. I also had a follow-up meeting with the dean of faculty a week after all interviews had wrapped up. After another week I got an email saying that they were still in the decision making process but were still actively considering my candidacy and that the chair of the department would reach out to me when they had more information to share. I wanted to know if the fact that the department chair would be the next person to contact me is a good sign? Is it common for the department chair to give rejections or do they more commonly come with good news? At the end of the day it's probably impossible to know for sure but I'm just curious if anyone has any insight.

Comment: When I hire, managers up the chain approve the selection, but I call the successful candidate.

Comment: The new version of this question is much better, but it substantially changes the question, invalidating the existing answers. I recommend you post the new version  in a separate post (note, one of the buttons above allows you to see all previous versions of the question, so you can get the "good version" of the text there). I'll go ahead and close this one out.

Comment: Where I work the chair is expressly forbidden to contact the candidate to avoid tangled lines of communications.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this question is getting downvoted is that it isn't really a question about the functioning of academia --- you are just asking us to guess the outcome of your job application based on tenuous and minor social cues.  No-one here has the power to go inside the mind of reviewers of job applications and make inferences based on tiny social cues like this, so in answer to your question: *we have no idea if that is a good sign or not, but it is probably just an irrelevant sign*.  More importantly, this site does not exist to reassure panicky job applicants who lack the patience to just wait for an outcome like everyone else.

Comment: I understand the points you're making, but I did ask a question about the functioning of academia. I specifically asked if anyone has any insight into the role the department chair plays with regards to the offer process. All I wanted was to know if anyone had any insight. And while yes, I am trying to gauge something about the status of my application, I did not ask you or anyone else to "guess" the status of it. I'm sorry you did not like my question, but the purpose of this site is to ask questions about academia, and you do not have to answer them. A simple downvote would have sufficed.

Comment: Thank-you for the explanation.  Typically we regard it as desirable to augment downvotes by an explanation if people have time for this; if the explanation can also provide an answer to the question, all the better.  That is usually considered beneficial insofar as it assists readers to undertand why a post is being heavily downvoted, so that they can improve future questions.  You seem to understand my critique well, and while we disagree, I hope this answer is helpful in undertanding a possible reason that this post is receiving downvotes.

Comment: Thank you both for your follow up comments. I agree with you that the original question was too ambiguous, probably because of my initial excitement. I've edited the question to be more explicit in its meaning as well as more general to appeal to a larger audience than just myself.